# Filter documents out of the facet count in enterprise search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elastic-enterprise-search

We use enterprise search indexes to store items that can be tagged by multiple tenants.
e.g

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "document 1",
    "tags": [
      { "company_id": 1, "tag_id": 1, "tag_name": "bla" },
      { "company_id": 2, "tag_id": 1, "tag_name": "bla" }
    ]
  }
]
```

I'm looking to find a way to retrieve all documents with only the tags of company 1

This request:

```
{
  "query": "",
  "facets": {
    "tags": {
      "type": "value"
    }
  },
  "sort": {
    "created": "desc"
  },
  "page": {
    "size": 20,
    "current": 1
  }
}
```

Is coming back with

```
...
    "facets": {
        "tags": [
            {
                "type": "value",
                "data": [
                    {
                        "value": "{\"company_id\":1,\"tag_id\":1,\"tag_name\":\"bla\"}",
                        "count": 1
                    },
                    {
                        "value": "{\"company_id\":2,\"tag_id\":1,\"tag_name\":\"bla\"}",
                        "count": 1
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
}
...
```

Can I modify the request in a way such that I get no tags by "company_id" = 2 ?

I have a solution that involves modifying the results to strip the extra data after they are retrieved but I'm looking for a better solution.

Comment: What's the aim of your query?
Do you just want to filter documents by company_id?
Do you want to count the number of documents with company_id=1 and a specific couple of <tag_id, tag_name>?

Comment: Could you also share your index mapping?